# JavascriptExecutor on Selenium Webdriver instance throwing exception on navigating to other page

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to record user actions - click , keypress etc other DOM events by injecting the javascript evenlisteners on webdriver instance. This works fine ! But as soon as I navigate to next page - it gives me an exception for an undefined function as the DOM has changed. How can I handle this exception?

Is there a way to keep capturing all the events in a temporary storage and read after all the web page navigation has completed.

Code :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
    .executeScript("(function() {
        var events = [];
        window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            events.push([+new Date(), 'click', [e.clientX, e.clientY], e.target.name, e.target.id]);
        }, true);
        window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
            events.push([+new Date(), 'keypress', e.target.name, e.target.id, String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)]);
        }, true);
        window._getEvents = function() {
            return events;
        };
    })();
");

response = (ArrayList)((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
    .executeScript("return window._getEvents();");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(events));
```

and then retrieve

```
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```